# A question regarding Surface Integrals and Stoke's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

Let $G$ be an open set in $ \Bbb R^3$ and $F:G \rightarrow \Bbb R^3-{0}$  a vectorial field of class $C^1$. Suppose that $S$ is an open set, contained in $G$, whose non-empty boundary $\delta S$, is also contained in $G$. Let $T$ denote the normal vector of an smooth parametrization of $ \delta S $ and let the angle between $T(x_0)$ and $F(x_0)$ be non-obtuse for every $x_0$ in $\delta S$  and also $ \int_S curl\ F \ dS =0$.

Show that $T(x_0)$ and $F(x_0)$ are orthogonal for every $x_0$ in $\delta S$.

I tried using Stoke's Theorem:

$$\int_S curl\ F \ dS = \int_{\theta(t)}F \ T \ dt = 0
$$

But I'm not sure if that is enough to guarantee that $F \ T =0$

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: If the angle between $F$ and $T$ is non-obtuse at a point, what can you say about $F\cdot T$ at that point? What does that tell you about $\int_{\partial S} F\cdot T$?

Comment: That'd imply that, is $\alpha$ is the angle between them, then $\cos \alpha < 0$ right?

Comment: Other way around: if $\alpha$ is non-obtuse, $\cos a \geq 0$.

Comment: Oh! You are right! And hence I could say that $F \cdot T$ could only be positive or zero, but as it's integral over $\delta S$ is zero then $F \cdot T =0$ ?

Comment: @WeierstraßRamirez Yes, exactly.